# Navigate From Activity to TabLayout / ViewPager Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to figure out how to navigate from an activity to a fragment that is hosted by a separate activity.

Even more complex is the destination activity hosts a TabLayout / ViewPager with 3 separate fragments. Here is the code for the adapter associated with the TabLayout / ViewPager. I am trying to navigate to the "NewFragment" section of the TabLayout / ViewPager:

```
 public class SectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new TrendingFragment();
            case 1:
                return new FollowingFragment();
            case 2:
                return new NewFragment();
            default:
                return new TrendingFragment();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getResources().getString(R.string.trending_text);
            case 1:
                return getResources().getString(R.string.following_text);
            case 2:
                return getResources().getString(R.string.new_text);
            default:
                return getResources().getString(R.string.trending_text);
        }
    }
}
```

I would think I would have to use an intent, but where I get confused is how I would ensure that the activity loads the NewFragment instead of the first fragment in the tab, the TrendingFragment.

Comment: The answer below should do it for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with something like this.

In the first activity:

```
int position = the fragment position in the target activity you want to open;
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TargetActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("fragmentPosition", position);
startActivity(intent);
```

Int the second activity, after view pager initialization:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int fragmentPosition = intent.getIntExtra("fragmentPosition");
viewPager.setCurrentItem(fragmentPosition);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I agree, this works, however it is probably worth checking if the bundle is null beforehand to determine whether to load the first tab or the desired tab coming from the aforementioned activity